# How do I group all rows of a certain column attribute and then order them from highest to lowest?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to list the highest rated game out of 6 games that users can play and then rate.

This is the table that stores the game ratings as well as other data:
[image]

I know I can count how many rows are of a certain rating, for example:

```
SELECT count(*) from gameSurvey where overallRating = 1
```

The rating is from 1-10 and there are 6 games that can be rated.

How can I count each of the rows for each rating (1-10) and then order the total of each rating from highest to lowest?

Comment: you can just use max function

Comment: the title of your question is not asking the same thing as the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just an aggregation query with a `group by`:

```
select overallRating, count(*) as num
from gameSurvey
group by overallRating
order by num desc;
```

Comment: I was going to do something very similar, but using the SELECT TOP instead. However, your solution seems to be much more robust

Answer (score 1):

Try using group by to group all your records by rating, followed by order by to sort according to rating.

```
SELECT overallRating, count(*) AS "Total"
FROM gameSurvey 
GROUP BY overallRating
ORDER BY overallRating desc
```